# C# internal static extern with InternalCall attribute - internal or external?

Tags: c#, .net

In [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200602/why-is-there-no-managed-md5-implementation-in-the-net-framework) I asked, a comment arose indicating that the .NET framework's `Array.Copy` method uses unmanaged code.  I went digging with [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) and found the signature one of the `Array.Copy` method overloads is defined as so:

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall), ReliabilityContract(Consistency.MayCorruptInstance, Cer.MayFail)]
internal static extern void Copy(Array sourceArray, int sourceIndex, Array destinationArray, int destinationIndex, int length, bool reliable);
```

After looking at this, I'm slightly confused.  The source of my confusion is the `extern` modifier which means ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e59b22c5.aspx) link):

> The extern modifier is used to declare
>   a method that is implemented
>   externally.

However, the method declaration is also decorated with a `MethodImplOptions.InternalCall` attribute, which indicates ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.methodimploptions.aspx) link):

> Specifies an internal call. An
>   internal call is a call to a method
>   that is implemented within the common
>   language runtime itself.

Can anyone explain this seemingly apparent contradiction?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I would have just commented on [leppie's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1211462/c-internal-static-extern-with-internalcall-attribute-internal-or-external/1211477#1211477) post, but it was getting a bit long.

I'm currently working on an experimental CLI implementation. There are many cases where a publicly exposed method (or property) can't be implemented without knowledge of how the virtual machine is implemented internally. One example is [OffsetToStringData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.runtimehelpers.offsettostringdata.aspx), which requires knowledge of how the memory manager allocates strings.

For cases like this, where there is no C# code to express the method, you can treat each call to the method in a special way *internal* to the JIT process. As an example here, replacing the `call` byte code with a `ldc.i4` (load constant integer) before passing it to the native code generator. The `InternalCall` flag means "The body of this method is treated in a special way by the runtime itself." There may or may not be an actual implementation - in several cases in my code the call is treated as an [intrinsic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intrinsic_function) by the JIT.

There are other cases where the JIT may have special information available that allows heavy optimization of a method. One example is the `Math` methods, where even though these [can be implemented in C#](http://www.netlib.org/cephes/), specifying `InternalCall` to make them effectively intrinsics has significant performance benefits.

In C#, a method has to have a body unless it is `abstract` or `extern`. The `extern` means a general "You can call this method from C# code, but the body of it is actually defined elsewhere.". When the JIT reaches a call to an `extern` method, it looks up where to find the body and behaves in different ways per the result.

- The `DllImport` attribute instructs the JIT to make a P/Invoke stub to call a native code implementation.
- The `InternalCall` flag instructs the JIT to treat the call in a self-defined way.
- (There are some others, but I don't have examples off the top of my head for their use.)

Answer (score 19):

`InternalCall` means provided by the framework.

`extern` says you are not providing code.

`extern` can be used in 2 general situations, like above, or with p/invoke.

With p/invoke, you simply tell the method where to get the implementation.

Comment: @leppie - I wish I could mark both yours and 280Z28's answers as accepted since you're both correct.  However, I feel that 280Z28's answer spells it out a little more and helped me to understand better, however, thanks a lot for your effort.

Comment: No problem, I have enough points already, I'll give him some more too :)