# Why does string.StartsWith("\u2D2D") always return true?

Tags: c#, string, unicode, startswith

I was fiddling around with parsing in C# and found that for every string I tried, `string.StartsWith("\u2D2D")` will return true. Why is that?

It seems it works with every char. Tried this code with .Net 4.5 the Debugger did not break.

```
for (char i = char.MinValue; i < char.MaxValue; i++)
{
    if(!i.ToString().StartsWith("\u2d2d"))
    {
        Debugger.Break();
    }
}
```

Comment: here's a line of code to check a bunch. returns `false` for me: `Enumerable.Range(0, 10000).Any(x => !((char)x).ToString().StartsWith("\u2D2D"))`

Comment: [Weird](https://ideone.com/q4kMsh). [Probably related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11467424/somestring-indexofsomestring-returns-1-instead-of-0-under-net-4/11467605#11467605).

Comment: It must be because all strings are Georgian :D

Comment: @CodeCaster: https://ideone.com/0QffbT maybe related?

Comment: @Caramiriel probably, but [`U+2D2D` is supposed to have a length of 1](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2d2d/index.htm).

Comment: True. Ordinal culture seems to give false, so I'm looking into that now.

Comment: Same for `2D2A` and the like.

Comment: Might be useful to look at the reference source for `String.StartsWith` here: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,8281103e6f23cb5c

Comment: U+2D2D was added in Unicode version 6.1 and it seems all 4 length characters of 6.1 have the same issue. From a few quick tests this seems the case for all versions > 6.0

Comment: Following the framework source, the comparison for non empty strings comes down to this line in `CompareInfo.cs`: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/globalization/compareinfo.cs,603, and its all native from there on. I don't understand the win32 API sufficiently to be able to debug what is going on with the windows native code.

Comment: A lot of the `UnicodeCategory.OtherNotAssigned` content matches this strange case. Can be checked with  `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.CompareInfo.Compare("", "" + (char)c, CompareOptions.None) == 0`, of which CurrentCulture = "en-US"

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think I'll have a try.

From what I get, is that U+2D2D was added in Unicode v6.1 ([source](https://codepoints.net/U+2D2D) / [source](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2d2d/index.htm)).

The .NET framework, or the native calls rather, support a lower version:

> The culture-sensitive sorting and casing rules used in string
>   comparison depend on the version of the .NET Framework. In the .NET
>   Framework 4.5 running on the Windows 8 operating system, sorting,
>   casing, normalization, and Unicode character information conforms to
>   the Unicode 6.0 standard. On other operating systems, it conforms to
>   the Unicode 5.0 standard. ([source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string(v=vs.110).aspx))

Thus it is required to mark it as an ignorable character, which behaves just as if the character wasn't even there.

> Character sets include ignorable characters, which are characters that
>   are not considered when performing a linguistic or culture-sensitive
>   comparison. ([source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zbz6f6h9(v=vs.110).aspx))

Example:

```
var culture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
int result = culture.CompareInfo.Compare("", "\u2D2D", CompareOptions.None);
Assert.AreEqual(0, result);
```

`string.StartsWith` uses a similar implementation, but uses `CompareInfo.IsPrefix(string, string, CompareOptions)` instead.

Comment: This makes more sense than the other answer, +1.

Comment: I just tested `.StartsWith()` with a blank string value, and it indicates true. I.e. `"abc".StartsWith("")` is *true*. Which makes sense, as it's basically saying that the underlying string starts with at least a *blank string*. This would indicate that when the underlying `Kernel32.dll` method `FindNLSStringEx` sees values it deems invalid, it simply strips them. (Or some other, lower-level method does.) The result is `string.StartsWith("")` when run.

Comment: @stakx: Thanks, but I don't mind if I don't. I was just wondering why this would happen in the first place, and maybe it would help me next time I face something like this myself. :)

Comment: @EBrown: In the case of an empty prefix (`""`), `FindNLSStringEx` doesn't actually get called. The special case of 0-length prefixes is taken care of on the .NET side. That aside, according to this answer this it is the *logical* reason why `anyString.StartsWith("\u2D2D")` yields true.

Comment: _I just tested .StartsWith() with a blank string value, and it indicates true._ Which is the defined (and logical) result. It does so if the string length == 0