# Why does “abcd”.StartsWith("ـــــــــــــ") return true?

Tags: c#, string, startswith

It was really strange for me. The following code returns `true` for every string. The character is `Arabic Tatweel (U+640)`.

```
"abcd".StartsWith("ـــــــــــــ") ;//returns true
```

But when I change the `StringComparer` to `StringComparison.Ordinal` it returns `false`

```
"abcd".StartsWith("ـــــــــــــ", StringComparison.Ordinal) ;//returns false
```

Can someone elaborate on the reasons for this behavior and **how I could know other characters that may have this behavior**?

Comment: [Not sure if this is a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29831410/why-does-string-startswith-u2d2d-always-return-true).

Comment: @John not exactly though

Comment: @Rahul I wasn't really sure, but I thought I'd link it in case it was helpful.

Comment: @John it's indeed helpful though

Comment: probably because its a Kashida and has no meaning in a word other than justitication

Comment: I doubt this is a duplicate at all

Comment: Your `ـــــــــــــ` string is a strange one, it is written from right to left. I guess there is some sort of characters that forces `CompareInfo.IsPrefix` method to return `true`.

Comment: Also note to future readers this is not an underscore its a https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0640/index.htm

Comment: The character is a `ModifierLetter` according to the `char.GetUnicodeCategory` method. It modifies the previous character. But in the OP's text there is no previous character. I suspect it's being ignored because of that.

Comment: yeah its like StartsWith("")

Comment: Not directly but related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29729391/regular-expression-arabic-characters-and-numbers-only