# How does the ChannelFactory<T>.CreateChannel work?

Tags: c#, wcf

If I have an interface:

```
public interface ISomething
{
    void DoAThing();
}
```

Then I instantiate it with the ChannelFactory:

```
var channel = new ChannelFactory<ISomething>().CreateChannel
```

I get an instance I can use.

Now, to close it I need to cast:

```
((IClientChannel)channel).Close
```

or

```
((IChannel)channel).Close
```

or

```
((ICommunicationObject)channel).Close
```

My **ISomething** interface does not inherit any of these interfaces.

So what kind of an object did the **CreateChannel** method return and how did it construct a dynamic object that was capable of implementing an interface it had no idea about until run time?

Comment: If you're comfortable digging around with a decompiler such as dotPeek or Reflector, you can go down the rabbit hole yourself and have a look...

Comment: I don't think it is a `dynamic` object, just a generated one. Generating code is relatively easy in .NET.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ChannelFactory.CreateChannel()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms575250.aspx) returns an implementation of [RealProxy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.proxies.realproxy.aspx), which is part of a set of tools usually referred to as TransparentProxy or "Remoting", which is a slightly outdated pre-wcf tech. For creating the actual class that implements the interface, it comes down to an internal framework-level method called [RemotingServices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.remotingservices.aspx).CreateTransparentProxy(...), that I haven't looked at but which is most likely a class builder/emitter of some sorts.

As you're asking, you might want to do something like this yourself. To implement an interface at runtime I recommend [Castle Dynamic Proxy](http://www.castleproject.org/projects/dynamicproxy/) which implements interfaces or abstract class without too much effort.

Comment: as to explain "internal framework-level method", theres a good response here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1211462/c-sharp-internal-static-extern-with-internalcall-attribute-internal-or-externa